# A "const" assertion error typescript with string array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to learn Typescript with React, but this error got in my way. I don't understand why is it even happening. Here it is.
Creating an array of strings that looks like colors array down there. I want to create types based on values of that array ("white" | "red" | "blue").

```
const colors = ["white", "red", "blue"] as const;
type Colors= typeof colors[number];
```

If I do it like this, it works, Colors has wanted types

```
const colorsArr = ["white", "red", "blue"];
const colors = colorsArr as const
type Colors = typeof colors[number]
```

But if I do it like this, it doesnt, and I'm getting "const" assertion error.

It doesn't even work if I copy colors array like [...colorsArr] or colorsArr.slice()

How does that work?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent enum?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty descriptive. `A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.`. I am also not sure what you expect to happen. The `as const` operator is used to narrow down literal types. `colorsArr` is  a  variable of type `string[]` and the type information about specific elements is already lost at that point.

Comment: This is a known [caveat with `const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats-1).  It only makes sense with literals because that's the only chance you have to preserve their strong types.  `const x = [0] as const` says "don't throw away the details of the array".  But `const x = [0]` infers `x` as `number[]`, and after that `x as const` is useless, like asking someone not to throw away last week's trash.  It's already gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is used with object/array/string/numeric *literal* values, to tell the compiler to preserve a more specific type for these values.  It cannot be applied to arbitrary expressions like another variable; this is a [documented caveat](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats-1).

If you write

```
const colors = ["white", "red", "blue"] as const;
```

then the compiler infers the type `readonly ["white", "red", "blue"]` for `colors`.  The compiler knows the value and position of each member of that array, and it won't let you change any of that.

---

On the other hand, if you leave off `as const`,

```
const colors = ["white", "red", "blue"];
```

then the compiler infers `string[]` for `colors`.  It's just an array of strings of unknown quantity, value, or order. That's often what people want, since maybe you'd like to write `colors.push("purple")`.  But the compiler has completely forgotten about the specific string literals in `colors` and what their order was.  That information is gone.

You can't write

```
const colors2 = colors as const; // error
```

and have it do anything.  Even if there weren't a compiler error, it still wouldn't have any useful effect.  The type of `colors` is `string[]`.  Writing `colors as const` can't retrieve the type information that was thrown away earlier.  That information is gone.  At best you'd get that `colors2` is also `string[]`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVA9jJBvAUE-S8awUALoWgDZoBOUSAvEgNoBEA7gBYCWpErAGiSsaEACaDhAI0oBXfgF0kIekRKkA3HgIB6HRXUVqdAFxJRIMcUoBPFhx59JI8c5nzWC7flI2YyAGEqWnomX380ADMjEOZgWTApCBoFDSQ9YS5efiQAH2FRCTzpOX4cAF8cHFBIWARkACE0clwCAzIYukZ7LKchFwl+90UtNrUOomMoACZuyZDlVWIyNIzkmlpvJHDA4K6wvwgozpm4hKSU9P0yGm5gAHMKoA)

```
type Colors= typeof colors[number];
```

Comment: Tyvm. Now I have better understanding on whats going on and it totally makes sense. Very well explained.